# Duplicating color RatingBar

Tags: android, ratingbar

I'm trying to create Rating bar on android, but when I'm launching my app, color in my bottom sheet is "duplicating" (see photo). How to fix this?

[image]

MainActivity.class

```
        RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.rating_bar);
        ratingBar.setEnabled(false);
        ratingBar.setRating(4);
```

xml with RatingBar

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/rating_bar"
    android:saveEnabled="false"
    android:isIndicator="true"
    android:rating="0"
    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove this line from ur code:

```
ratingBar.setEnabled(false);
```